# Django annotate, access current row to traverse foreign keys

Tags: django, django-orm

I have these models:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    profit = models.FloatField()
    expenses = models.FloatField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)

class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

given `ids = [a list of seller ids...]`, I need a table like this:

```
Store 1 -> sum of profits - sum of expenses of all sellers in ids and in store 1
Store 2 -> sum of profits - sum of expenses of all sellers in ids and in store 2
...
```

I can get all the stores like this:

```
sellers = Seller.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
q = Store.objects.filter(id__in=sellers.values("store_id"))
```

At this point I'd iterate over `q` but that would defy the point of having an ORM.

The alternative is using `.annotate()` but how can I tell `.annotate` to grab the sum of all profits of all sellers in store N?

Comment: How are `Sale`s linked here to a `Seller`? Did you forget a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make things too complicated. You can annotate your `Store` with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Store.objects.annotate(
    balance=Sum('seller__sale__profit') - Sum('seller__sale__expenses')
)
```

Or with a single aggregate, and two [**`F`**-expressions [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Store.objects.annotate(
    balance=Sum(F('seller__sale__profit') - F('seller__sale__expenses'))
)
```

All the `Store`s that arise from *this* queryset, will have an extra attribute named `.balance` that contains the sum of the `profit`s of the `Sale`s related to the `Seller`s that are related to that `Store` minus the `expenses`s of the `Sale`s related to the `Seller`s that are related to that `Store`. In case there are *no* such sales, the `.balance` will be `None`, the sum can be zero as well (if all profits sum up to the same amount as all expenses).

You can calculate the balance of the `Store`s by taking into account only the sales of a specific date with:

```
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Store.objects.filter(
    seller__sale__date=date(2019, 9, 1)
).annotate(
    balance=Sum(F('seller__sale__profit') - F('seller__sale__expenses'))
)
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT store.id, store.name, store.country_id
       SUM((sale.profit - sale.expenses)) AS balance
FROM store
INNER JOIN seller ON store.id = seller.store_id
INNER JOIN sale ON seller.id = sale.seller_id
WHERE sale.date = 2019-09-01
GROUP BY store.id
```

By filtering, you will omit `Store`s that had no `Sale` on that day. You can include those by slightly changing the condition:

```
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Q

Store.objects.annotate(
    balance=Sum(
        F('seller__sale__profit') - F('seller__sale__expenses'),
        filter=Q(seller__sales__date=date(2019, 9, 1))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will accept as soon as I can! Quick off-topic: do you think it is possible to filter Sales by a unique date?

Comment: @Saturnix: yes, you can calculate the balance of all sales for a specific date.

Comment: @Saturnix: see edit: this will calculate the balance of sales that happened on September 1st.